# When to use custom class loading code instead of defining class path in manifest.mf file?

Tags: java, classloader

Lets say we want to package our Java application into a jar file (including the dependencies). The dependencies are copied into one separate directory (lets say libs/). I have read that are two approaches to make the java launcher find these classes:

1) Implement a custom class loader code (loader/launcher pattern) that will load necessary classes before the main code of the application is executed (it is described here: http://vladimirvivien.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/86/)

2) Add the libs/ directory to the "Class-Path:" header in meta-inf/manifest.fm

Which solution is better and why?

Comment: Have you considered adding the extra classes in a classpath specified on the command line? It is worth considering all other options before choosing custom class loading tricks.

Comment: The Class-Path line in the manifest is simple, straightforward, and has been a Java standard for years.  I see no reason to re-invent that functionality.